# Sp2013 warning : You don't appear to have permission to view the account credentials for this result source

Tags: 2013, search-results

I have a webpart on my homepage where you can see the most viewed items. I am looking for the query and logic from this search webpart. I went to the settings of this webpart. Then I go to the query. After this I clicked on a link which bringing me to this page:

http://myCompany.com/_layouts/15/ManageResultSources.aspx?level=site

On this page I see a list with many resultsources. I clicked on the resultSource which I need to investigate and get on this page:

http://myCompany.com/_layouts/15/EditResultSource.aspx?level=site&sourceid=fc7904f2%2D9403%2D4a3b%2D88cb%2D17df383554df&view=1

On this page I see all the controls are read only. So I cannot change the settings. Isee also a warning message:

> You don't appear to have permission to view the account credentials
>   for this result source. You need permissions at the level at which the
>   result source was created. For example, only an account with
>   administrator permissions for a Search Service application can view
>   the account credentials for a result source created at that level.

Does someone know why I got this warning? I would like to change some settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, are you an administrator of the Search Service Application? Check in Central Administration -> Service Applications and mark the row of your Search Service Application and click Administrators in the ribbon.

Comment: yes, I did already check this. I add my self to the administrators and grant full permission. I am logged in with a farm account. It is possible to add a new resultSource.

Comment: And is the Result Source added at farm level? because if it is added on Site Collection level, you need to be Site Admin of that collection

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same. On the settings page, there are two options which are very similar:

- Search settings, below heading 'Search'
- Search settings, below Site Collection Administration

The link to use to alter a Content source, must be the same link you used to create the Content source.

This did the trick for me. Hopefully this is helpfull for others.